# How to use regex to reduce cardinality of istio metrics which caused istio side car crash

Tags: metrics, istio, istio-sidecar, istio-prometheus, common-expression-language

I am using istio as my kubernetes service mesh. And I want to use metrics such as istio_requests_total as my SLI. I need to add a customized label "request_url_path" into those metrics, whose value is set to the real request url(request.url).

However, after I apply those customization at my metrics, during my load tests, istio-proxy sidecar keeps crashing because of OOMKilled.

After investigation, I think it was cause by the dynamic part inside the request.url(such as some GUID, or random numbers), for example: `/api/user/27ee8e1c8bcedd1becerqfe`

I want to remove those dynamic parts inside the url and only apply those static part, below is my test code for applying a customized metrics with telemetry v2. It checks whether the url path include "login", or "logout", or "api/user", if yes, use "login", or "logout", or "api/user" as the label's value, otherwise, use "unknown" as the label's value.

However, below configuration doesn't work.

It seems the `find` function(for Common Expression Language regex) is not defined in istio.

Could you provide some suggestions on how can I solve my problem? Thanks a lot!!

```yaml
apiVersion: telemetry.istio.io/v1alpha1
kind: Telemetry
metadata:
  name: add-tags
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  metrics:
    - providers:
        - name: prometheus
      overrides:
        - match:
            metric: REQUEST_COUNT
          tagOverrides:
            request_url_path:
              value: request.url_path.matches('^/(login|logout|api/user).*$')?request.url_path.find('/(login|logout|/api/user)'):"unknown"
```

Answer (score 1):

We ended up with using lua envoyfilter to remove the Guid part inside the request path and add this as a http request header.
Then add this extra header as a istio metrics dimension.

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: EnvoyFilter
metadata:
  name: request-add-uri-headers-filter
  namespace: istio-system
spec:
  configPatches:
  - applyTo: HTTP_FILTER
    match:
      context: SIDECAR_INBOUND
      listener:
        filterChain:
          filter:
            name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            subFilter:
              name: envoy.filters.http.router
    patch:
      operation: INSERT_BEFORE
      value:
        name: envoy.lua
        typed_config:
          '@type': type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.lua.v3.Lua
          inlineCode: |
            function envoy_on_request(request_handle)
              -- Log information about the request
              local x = "%x"
              local t = { x:rep(8), x:rep(4), x:rep(4), x:rep(4), x:rep(12) }
              local pattern_guid = table.concat(t, '%-')
              local pattern_uri = '([^%?]+).*'
              local uripath = string.match(request_handle:headers():get(":path"),pattern_uri)
              local strippedpath = string.gsub(uripath,pattern_guid,'{GUID}')
              request_handle:logInfo("Path: "..strippedpath)
              request_handle:headers():add("request_path_header", strippedpath)
            end
```